# PHP PDO Is there a way to disable named placeholders ( Oracle AUTOINCREMENT issue )

Tags: oracle, pdo, placeholder, auto-increment, named

i am creating table in oracle ( odbc connection - has to be ). And i want to create auto increment column. That is not problem. The query i need to perform is following :

```
CREATE TRIGGER TBIUR_FOLDER_FOLDER_ID
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
OF
FOLDER_ID
ON FOLDER
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
IF :NEW."FOLDER_ID" IS NULL 
 THEN SELECT "SQ_FOLDER_FOLDER_ID".NEXTVAL INTO :NEW."FOLDER_ID" FROM dual;
END IF;
END;
```

The problem is in :NEW keyword , PDO takes it as named parameter so i am unable to create the trigger properly . When i check in the database the create query is :

```
IF :1."FOLDER_ID" IS NULL
```

so :NEW is replaced by :1 :/ and i do not know what to do ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
You can disable prepared statements parsing at all.
Just don't use them for this query, as it obviously don't need them. Just run it using `query()` or `exec()`

Comment: Hi,
  thanks , but it is strange , i am using ->query and it does not work, but ->exec directly works ok. ... Strange but thanks you saved my day

Comment: On php.net there is no difference in description of $statement parameter of query() and exec() methods. But obviosly there is something different done with it. :/

Comment: Yes. query() deals with single query while exec() does send everything you wish, including dumps, procedures, triggers and such